# Is Norton Mobile Security for Kindle Fire a Fraud? (or Malware?)

Tags: malware

I downloaded a security app to my ***Kindle Fire*** a few months ago, (in this case **[Norton Mobile Security](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008R5RGAC)**), and I am doubting it's authenticity now.

Why?
Because of these reasons:

***Reason 1:*** The 5-star ratings largely consist of ratings with the title "**Five Stars**".

***Reason 2:*** The developer's name is "***Norton By Symantec***", while it would make more sense for it to just be "***Symantec***".

***Reason 3:*** The ridiculous amount of permissions, including these:

**A:** Read the user's contacts data

**B:** Read the low-level system log files

**C:** Initiate a phone call without going through the Dialer user interface for the 
user to confirm the call being placed

**D:** Read SMS messages

**E:** Modify of the telephony state - power on, mmi, etc

**F:** Write (but not read) the user's calendar data

**G:** Discover and pair bluetooth devices

**H:** Open windows using the type TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, shown on top of all other applications

**I:** Read the user's calendar data

**J:** Get notified that the operating system has finished booting

**K:** Write to external storage

***Reason 4:*** The fact that the software is "***Free***".

***Summary:*** Should I remove (or force stop) it?

Comment: Because I hear that standard Norton Security also takes a lot of information, though, ok I will remove it.

Comment: A little research goes a long way. You provided your own guidance to your answers:

Reason 1: On the app page, all reviews show real titles

Reason 2: If you go to the official Norton site, it shows "Norton by Symantec". 

Reason 3: If you compare these permissions to any other AV package, you will note that they are the same. 

Reason 4: There are tons of free AV packages.

Comment: Android [wasn't designed with antiviruses in mind](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32285/how-do-anti-virus-apps-for-android-work) and generally [don't add much value](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/104827-android-antivirus-apps-are-useless-heres-what-to-do-instead/2). The Norton one is [well-ranked](https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/mobile-devices/android/july-2016/norton-norton-mobile-security-3.15-162622/), though ultimately probaby useless for most general users.